# How long does it take to get to "Olympiad-Bronze-level" of math problem solving ability from no competition experience?

Tags: soft-question, contest-math

Is it possible to go from almost zero math competition experience to "Olympiad-Bronze-level" within a span of ~3 years?

---

I am currently double-majoring in Maths and Mathematical Statistics, but am sort of starting to experience anxiety fron my lack of problem-solving ability.

To maintain high grades, I am finding that I need to study the course material well ahead of the semester in the holidays. For instance, I think I would have struggled to immensely to have even passed my Analysis class had I not worked through most of Baby Rudin's Textbook the semester break before.

Despite the overlap, I feel like these competition style problems are still quite different to the maths I learn in undergrad courses, and although I think did relatively well in some hard courses—Analysis and Abstract Algebra—I don't think many of the skills are transferring for me over to competition questions, and hence need to dedicate time to learning to solve them separately.

**A bit of context:**

I used to be decent at maths growing up, had never felt high school maths challenging. I did a bit of competition math in early high school - did reasonably well I think (top 1% of scorers in Australia). However, the last time I did maths competitions "seriously" was 4 years ago, and those were mainly non-proof based competitions.

Now, even when I look back to the kiddie math problems, I can barely solve any of them. Looking back, I had never properly/formally learnt the common "tricks" and theory required (i.e., CRT or FLT in number theory, or the pigeon-hole principle) - the way that I had studied for them was doing past practice questions and studying the solutions whenever some new trick popped-up, then memorising the "tricks" for when the actual exam came around. As such, I currently have quite a bad gauge of my actual problem-solving abilities.

I am currently working through AOPS Volume 1 now, and am finding that I have atrocious - almost non-existant problem solving abilities now. I constantly have to peak at the solution to solve problems, and sometimes, I don't even understand the solution completely, constantly making me think, "How on earth would I have thought of that!?!" Some of these competition solutions are so creative that I feel as if I will never ever be able to compose similar ones, no matter how much I study.

How much can a math major like me reasonably expect to improve in terms of competition problem solving ability before I graduate? I am thinking of doing ~5 hrs a day in the holidays, but think that I will need focus almost exclusively on the undergrad level math classes during the actual semesters.

Comment: What is "actual math" to you? I don't mean to dismiss your claim, and while I would love to potentially do reserach level mathematics one day,  I am currently far from that level,a nd quite frankly I don't know if I'd even make it. Currently, I feel as if I lack mathematical maturity and problem solving ability in general—to the extent that I struggle with getting good grades in undergraduate classes and solving the harder Undergrad questions in exams. A lot of my friends from math Olympiad backgrounds seem to be able to follow along very easily—are you perhaps attributing this to talent/IQ?

Comment: @HollandDavis One thing I can almost guarantee you, is that innate talent (except maybe at the highest level) is overshadowed by hard work at the undergrad and higher level. Kudos to you for working on material before the semester. Again, a focus on understanding the material, why mathematicians care about certain objects, and how concepts can be applied, would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe, but it took me 3 full years to make it from the moderate problem solving ability (I had practiced occasional problem solving for 7 years as a schoolboy before) to the IMO level with rather intensive supervised training (though I ended with gold rather than bronze). So, I wouldn't keep the hopes too high.

As to Mariano's remark, I'm still using the skills I acquired doing competition level mathematics in my professional work (I'm not sure how good the latter is, but some people around consider me not hopelessly dumb). The only real difference I see is the time constraint: in the "competition math" you need to figure it out in a few hours while in "actual math" you may afford a few years. Some people would also argue that in real math you don't need to fully answer the question as stated but can just publish "something relevant" instead, but I prefer to put a rather high threshold on the "relevancy" level in such cases (the sort of discipline one acquires from competition math as well).

The moral is that you can (and, with due effort, will) get better in problem solving but it takes time and, unless you are a genius (I'm not), the progress will be painstakingly slow, at least in the beginning. Just do not let this discourage you: you'll get there at some point :-)

Answer (score 5):

1. It's more about the time and effort that you put in. If you can set aside 2-4 hours a day to focus on (pretty much anything), you can make a lot of progress in a year.
2. After that it's having the right direction (esp to suit your learning style). Broadly speaking,

- If you don't understand the (presumably well-written) solution completely, it's often that you don't understand the technique, so read up on that first.
- Once you understand the technique, read the solution line by line to see if you can figure out the next step or direction to take.
- Once you learnt the technique, work on the problem and see how you can deduce the crux or ideas involved. If you're stuck, read one line/paragraph of the solution.

IE If you spend 2 hours trying to work on a basic problem and making no progress, I'd argue that you time is much better spent reading up on the ideas involved, and then trying another basic problem.

3. (Very speculative and untested, but I'm willing to stand by it) Given those in place, I'm of the opinion that 4 hours a day consistently for a year can get a  motivated high-schooler to solve problems 1 and 4 of the IMO. That's at least a HM, potentially a bronze in most years.

Comment: I'm quite interested in your last claim, "4 hours a day consistently for a year can get a motivated high-schooler to solve problems 1 and 4 of the IMO". Do you mind perhaps elaborating on it a bit? That is, how would you propose a driven student go about spending those "4 hours a day", and what would a rough roadmap with milestones look like? I tend to be quite bad at determining when to "move on", and will get stuck in "tutorial hell" with several textbooks online. 


(Bbviously, I am no longer a high schooler, but my skills might as well be comparable to one)

Comment: For e.g., I highly agree with your point of trying more basic problems first. I am thinking of following a study schedule like this:

Polya's how to solve it --> AOPS Vol 1 --> AOPS vol 2 --> get quite comfortable with  AMC 10/12 problems --> Arthur Engel's problem solving strategies --> get comfortable with AIME level problems --> IMO level problems.

However, I don't see how a plan like this one can be fit into the time-frame of a year as you claimed. I tend to study quite linearly; that is, read textbook 1 cover-cover --> read textbook 2 cover-cover, and so on.

Comment: I'm making assumptions about their ability and prior knowledge, in particular being able to do AMC 10/12 problems (basic theorems, able to set up equations, work through calculations, etc).  $\quad$ It's not just about knowledge, but more about how well you can apply what you know in slightly-novel situations. EG If you know how completing the square works, can you use it to factorize $a^4 + 4$?  $\quad$ I might recommend starting from Arthur Engel. Cover a chapter every few days, working through the problems and only reading solutions line by line, and see how difficult that is.

Comment: As to how to spend the time: 1/ Identify the techniques they want to learn (with the understanding that they might not know everything that's available, and also that not every technique needs to be learnt), 2/ Find a suitable book/notes to follow (this can be difficult, though generally follow the well-known sources), 3/ Actively work on problems by thinking about A/ What technique is involved, and do you know it well, B/ How would you apply it C/ When stuck, read the next line of the solution and see if that's something you reasonably would have come up with, else go back to A.